# Windows Script Host Error when script run in command prompt

Tags: vbscript

I got the following error when I ran a script at the command prompt:

```
Windows Script Host Error
--------------------------
Script : D:\viru\vbs\sample.vbs
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Expected Statement
Code : 800A0400
Source: Microsoft VBScript Compilation Error.
```

What does it mean, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Post your script.  We have no idea what the script is trying to do. It sounds like your script probably has a syntax problem.

Comment: Sounds like you have an error on line 1 of your code. You should probably post it... your code that is.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1 char 1. It looks like due to file encoding. 
Save your script file as UTF-8 Without Bom, ANSI or Unicode (Little Endian) encoded.